# Rename value added to an object with stored reactive values

Tags: r, shiny

I create an object in which I store reactive values with `shiny` and is similar to a list. And then I add a new value named "contents". Then I want to rename this value but despite using `names()` I still get :

```
fileOption[[4]]
[1] "contents"
```

## code

```
library(shiny)
library(rlist)
    fileOption <- reactiveValues(currentOptions=c("D.B","T.C","R.H","D.G.I","D.C.H","L.D.P"))
    fileOption = list.append(fileOption,"contents")
    names(fileOption)[[4]]<-"new"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what do you mean by rename.

But if you are expecting `fileOption[[4]]` to give you `new` then this is the way of going about it.

````
``` r
library(shiny)
library(rlist)
fileOption <- reactiveValues(currentOptions=c("D.B","T.C","R.H","D.G.I","D.C.H","L.D.P"))
fileOption = list.append(fileOption,"contents")
#names(fileOption)[[4]]<-"new"
fileOption[[4]]<-"new"

fileOption[[4]]
#> [1] "new"


fileOption
#> $impl
#> <ReactiveValues>
#>   Public:
#>     .allValuesDeps: environment
#>     .dedupe: TRUE
#>     .dependents: environment
#>     .label: reactiveValues8359
#>     .metadata: environment
#>     .namesDeps: environment
#>     .setLabel: function (label) 
#>     .values: environment
#>     .valuesDeps: environment
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     freeze: function (key) 
#>     get: function (key) 
#>     getMeta: function (key, metaKey) 
#>     initialize: function (dedupe = TRUE) 
#>     isFrozen: function (key) 
#>     mset: function (lst) 
#>     names: function () 
#>     self: ReactiveValues, R6
#>     set: function (key, value) 
#>     setMeta: function (key, metaKey, value) 
#>     thaw: function (key) 
#>     toList: function (all.names = FALSE) 
#> 
#> $readonly
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $ns
#> function (x) 
#> x
#> <bytecode: 0x7fefb219b1a0>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "new"

names(fileOption)
#> [1] "impl"     "readonly" "ns"       ""
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>
````

Comment: Your approach works based on the question but I may need to give a more specific example of my case.